# Removing element from dynamic list

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, dynamic-list

i have a dynamic list, where a is the current spot, a-> prev - previous element, a-> next - the next element, I need to delete one element of the list (and set the previous/next of the adjacent elements to one another)

```
if(a->va == var && a->pa == pav){
        a -> prev -> next = a -> next;
        a -> next -> prev = a -> prev;
        delete a;
    }
```

Comment: You need to describe your problem better. *It doesn't work like this* is not a helpful diagnosis.

Comment: I need to delete just 1 element of the list

Comment: @user2921071 Please consult with [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to handle the edge cases.

If the found element is the first one in the list, `a -> prev` is NULL.

Similarly, if it's the last, `a -> next` is NULL.

Comment: How do you know there isn't a sentinel node?

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work

Comment: I don't...... but it looks a  good assumption to me.

Comment: @user2921071: incorrect implementation? and not enough information in the question... use a debugger?

Comment: got it... you cant delete a directly, you need to create another variable, then give it the meaning of a, give a the meaning of a->prev/next, and then delete the created variable

Comment: that makes no sense whatsoever, but we don't see your code...